# Cropped Label due to Big Font

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've got this problem :

[image]

The text in the label is cropped.

This is my code:

```
public var MenuSkin:GUISkin;

function OnGUI () {
GUI.skin = MenuSkin;
GUI.skin.font = myfont;
GUI.Label ( new Rect (Screen.width-310,Screen.height/2,300,50), "Number is 16");
}
```

The label is cropped. How do i fix it without changing the font because i need bigger font.

Thank you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use style.CalSize() function to get the exact rect needed:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    var style = GUI.skin.label;
    var size = style.CalcSize(new GUIContent("Number is 16")); // ****

    GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width - size.x - 100, 
              Screen.height / 2, size.x, size.y), "Number is 16");
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i found an other solution i changed (Screen.width-310,Screen.height/2,300,50) to (Screen.width/3,Screen.height/6,30000,5000) and now no problem :D